# return envelope with nusoap

Tags: php, soap

I'm new with nusoap and developped a webservice server.
I have to return a response like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<UpdateLeadResponse xmlns="http://icrm.pat.it/fiat/ws">
  <UpdateLeadResult>
    <ID>string</ID>
    <ResultCode>OK</ResultCode>
    <ResultDescription>string</ResultDescription>
  </UpdateLeadResult>
</UpdateLeadResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

i've tried to return a StdClass

```
$rep = new StdClass();
$test = new stdClass();
$test->LeadID = "";
$test->ResultCode = "OtherError";
$test->ResultDescription = $errorDesc;
$rep->UpdateLeadResult = $test;
```

I use yii framework so in my function, i declare this

```
/**
    * @param string $sXml
    * @param string $sFilters
    * @return mixedHello you !
    * @soap
    */
```

But now when i test with SoapUI, i receive this so how can i remove the enclosed tag 'return'

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:WebServControllerwsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:ProcessRequestResponse>
     <return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct">
        <UpdateLeadResult xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct">
           <LeadID xsi:type="xsd:string"></LeadID>
           <ResultCode xsi:type="xsd:string">OK</ResultCode>
           <ResultDescription xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
        </UpdateLeadResult>
     </return>
  </ns1:ProcessRequestResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I found this post and effectively the wsdl i must implement can't contain this retrun tag so i have to remove this one

[link]http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=2877[/link]

But i don't know where making the change in nusoap.

Thanks for your help